# error while installing GNS3 server from GitHub using pypi2pkgbuild to create PKGBUILD and install everything via pacman

Tags: github, pkgbuild

I'm trying to install GNS3 on my Manjaro machine. I followed along with this medium blog https://medium.com/@Ninja/install-gns3-on-arch-manjaro-linux-the-right-way-c5a3c4fa337d

the problem is when I use the command "pypi2pkgalias git+file://$PWD" in steps 16 and 17 to install GNS3 Server from GitHub using pypi2pkgbuild to create PKGBUILD and install everything via pacman, I always get that error!

```
Cloning into 'gns3-gui'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 36655, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36655/36655), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7135/7135), done.
remote: Total 36655 (delta 29225), reused 36655 (delta 29225)
Receiving objects: 100% (36655/36655), 57.32 MiB | 37.43 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29225/29225), done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 1477, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 1454, in main
    create_package(name, Options(**vars(args), is_dep=False))
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 1253, in create_package
    pkg = dispatch_package_builder(name, options)
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 1245, in dispatch_package_builder
    ref = PackageRef(
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 695, in __init__
    self.info = _get_info(
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 601, in _get_info
    info = locals()[f"_get_info_{source}"]()
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 542, in _get_info_git
    metadata = _get_metadata(
  File "/usr/bin/pypi2pkgbuild.py", line 505, in _get_metadata
    "CFLAGS": get_makepkg_conf()["CFLAGS"],
KeyError: 'CFLAGS'
```

can you help me please with that?

Answer (score 0):

I am running 5.5.16–1-MANJARO, so I cannot speak for others.

Look into the github repo closed [issues](https://github.com/anntzer/pypi2pkgbuild/issues/15) and just substitute the installation command with `yay -S python-pypi2pkgbuild-git --noconfirm`.

Everything works fine then for me.